# Kibana4 Log Levels not shown

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, elastic-stack

We've got an ELK setup. All logfiles are collected successfully and pushed into elasticsearch. Then we're using kibana 4 to visualize the logs. But there is only WARN as 'level' shown. Within the elasticsearch index there are many more and all other 'level's. But these are not shown. All other fields in the index, where multiple values are available are shown, except 'level'.
Is this a bug or is there something wrong in the default configuration?

Comment: What visualization are you using? And what aggregate did you apply?

Comment: Are you writing any extra customized fields in logstash(like loglevel) etc...

Comment: No, I haven't used any visualization. It's just plain out of the box.

Comment: We've got two fields, named "name" and "instance", which are added by the file input.

Comment: I asked you in reference to this line:
`Then we're using kibana 4 to visualize the logs. But there is only WARN as 'level' shown`
You might be using some visualization (line graph, bar chart, etc), right?
And if you're using the inbuilt charts, you also might have used an aggregation to bucket the X-axis and a sub-aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug within logstash. It corrupted some log-events so only these wich have the loglevel WARN were processed correctly. So only these events are shown.

Thanks for your help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you tried and how did you end up **not** getting all level in Kibana. Because you've mentioned:

> Then we're using kibana 4 to visualize the logs.But there is only WARN as 'level' shown.

This does not make it clear what kind/type of (out of the box) visualization (graph, chart, data table, etc) is being used and what aggregation(s) are implemented.

Also, When you say

> Within the elasticsearch index there are many more and all other
>   'level's. But these are not shown.

I'd assume that the everything is implemented/configured correctly at the logstash end (the grok filter, and the pattern if you're using one)

I recently did something similar (parse and visualize tomcat logs) and dealt with the same 'level' issue. I discovered that in Kibana while using a (sub)aggregation in any visualization, when you choose **Significant Terms -> fieldname** it might neglect the value that is very less compared to other values of that field. Ex if occurrence frequency of `WARN >>> ERROR` in the `level` field for the given timeframe, Kibana will show only `WARN` irrespective of the size that you put in. This is what it is meant for - showing only **significant** terms.

> To overcome this, use **Terms -> Field -> fieldname**. Set **Order** to Top/Bottom
>   and most importantly, **Size** to **0**.

You'll see every value for that field irrespective of its occurrence frequency. Hope this helps.

PS: Choosing bottom gets you slight relief from that default `GREEN` color in the Kibana visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're on the Discover tab, and are commenting on the values shown in the facets on the left side.

These values are generated from the documents in the current table (default is the most recent 500 rows returned by your query), *not* from the results of the entire query.

So, if the most recent messages are all WARN, that's all that will show in the facet on the left side.

To confirm this theory, exclude the WARN messages and see if your other levels appear.